# Passing an array of arbitrary length as parameters to another method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml-rpc

I have several methods that sends a variable length array to another method which then makes an XML::RPC call to an API.

Now, how do I pass these into XML::RPC when they are of an undefined length?

```
def call_rpc(api_call, array_of_values)
  client.call(
    remote_call, 
    username, 
    password, 
    value_in_array_of_values_1,
    ...,
    value_in_array_of_values_n
  )
end
```

I have been scratching my head for this one and I can't seem to figure it out. Is it possible to do this in a nice way? Maybe I have overlooked something?

Comment: See the [ruby splat operator](http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/) -- note [the call to sprintf here](http://pivotallabs.com/users/nick/blog/articles/438-ruby-pearls-vol-1-the-splat) Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I have been looking at but the example with sprintf made it all clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoken in your language:

```
def call_rpc(api_call, array_of_values)
  client.call(
    remote_call, 
    username, 
    password, 
    *array_of_values
  )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby splat/collect operator `*` may help you. It works by converting arrays to comma seperated expressions and vice versa.

#### Collecting parameters into an array

```
*collected = 1, 3, 5, 7
puts collected
# => [1,3,5,7]

def collect_example(a_param, another_param, *all_others)
  puts all_others
end

collect_example("a","b","c","d","e")
# => ["c","d","e"]
```

#### Splatting  an array into parameters

```
an_array = [2,4,6,8]
first, second, third, fourth = *an_array
puts second # => 4

def splat_example(a, b, c)
  puts "#{a} is a #{b} #{c}"
end

param_array = ["Mango","sweet","fruit"]
splat_example(*param_array)
# => Mango is a sweet fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f (a=nil, b=nil, c=nil)
    [a,b,c]
end

f(*[1,2]) # => [1, 2, nil]
```

Comment: Dunno why someone downvoted this; perhaps lack of explanation? This shows that the Ruby splat operator allows you to convert an array into individual parameters in a method call.

Comment: I downvoted for the lack of an explanation and I'll be happy to remove it once an explanation is in there :)

Comment: I don't think I have to explain three characters of solution code. For explanation there were already links in question comment. Should I have to copy/paste/repost them? NO.